# Add read more link if the content exceeds specified height of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a pre tag inside a span tag which have several line of content(the content is coming at run time from database),

```
<span height="30px;">
<pre>  
    Line-1 content
    Line-2 content
    Line-3 content
    Line-4 content
    Line-5 content
    Line-6 content
    Line-7 content
    Line-8 content
    Line-9 content
</pre> 
</span>
```

I have specified the height of span as "30px". Now what i want to to is, if the content as exceeding my span height "30px", then my js will add a readmore link at the end of the span content. So something like this should be rendered:

```
<span>
<pre>  
    Line-1 content
    Line-2 content
    Line-3 content
    Line-4 content
    Line-5 content..<a href="wholeContent.html">Readmore</a>
</pre> 
</span>
```

I tried on this and i came up with this solution, but this is adding a readmore link on the basis of no. of characters, but i want to do this on the basis of height:

```
var k = 1;
        $('.spanContent pre').each(function (event) {
            var max_height = 285;
            console.log($(this).height());
            if ($(this).height() > max_height) {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var short_content = $(this).html().substr(0, 200);
                var long_content = $(this).html();
                $(this).html(short_content +
                             '<a href="#" class="read_more"  onClick="showPopup(' + id + ');">...Read More</a>' +
                             '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;">' + long_content + '</span>');
                k++;
            }
        });
```

Solution to the problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Better solution is that you set every line in one tag and hide overflow element.

Comment: How can i set every line in one tag.? Since the content could be anything(Not a fixed content).

Comment: If you generate html, you can set every row text in one tag.

Comment: So, i will specify no. of characters for each row. So if the text will reach number of character, it will be added in one tag. similarly for other, and so on. This is what you are trying to say.?

Comment: @Mohammad i am waiting for your response.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dmsge7tn/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126598/discussion-between-dilip-kumar-yadav-and-mohammad).